# Hibernate/JPA and PostgreSQL - Primary Key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, postgresql, primary-key

I'm trying to implement some basic entities using Hibernate/JPA.  Initially the code was deployed on MySQL and was working fine.  Now, I'm porting it over to use PostgreSQL.  In MySQL, my entity class defines its primary key as an auto-incrementing long value with the following syntax:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

However, I've found that I get errors with PostgreSQL when I try and insert numerous records at a time.  What do I need to annotate my primary key with to get the same auto-incrementing behavior in PostgreSQL as I have with MySQL?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: GenerationType.AUTO shouldn't cause an issue with any database. Can you post the exception and / or your insertion code? It's worth noting that on MySQL, GenerationType.AUTO converts to the increment type whereas on PostgreSQL, it uses sequence by default. See the doc here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id for a description

Comment: I'll try that once more and then post the exception I'm getting.  The way I have my entity classes setup is to have an abstract base class with the id defined and the @MappedSuperclass annotation on it, and then derive the rest of my entities from there.  Do you think that will create a problem in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you inserting with JPA `persist()` and `merge()` or direct SQL?  `GenerationType.AUTO` means "the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy" (JPA 2.0 Final Release, Section 11.1.17).  It does not necessarily imply a sequence relation.  Only `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` forces the JPA provider to use a sequence.  The question is currently too vague to be sure, but perhaps Hibernate decided to generate `id` with a table under Postgres and perhaps you're running SQL expecting a nonexistent default sequence value for column `id`.  Please show the Postgres relations (psql's `\d`).

Comment: I'm generating 100 test rows using a for loop.  I create each entity and set every value except for the id (primary key) and then perform a JPA persist() to store it.  I'll increase the loglevel and get more information to post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solved the issue.  Previously -- in my MySQL implementation -- I made use of an abstract base class with the following signature:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractDomainEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id = null;

        ...
}
```

...and then I extended this in each of my remaining entities.  I've since pushed this attribute down into the entities themselves, and configured the @GenerationType as SEQUENCE.  For example:

```
public class UserProfileBean extends AbstractIdentifiedDomainEntitiy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "profile_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "profile_seq", sequenceName = "profile_seq")
    private Long id = null;

        ...
}
```

By doing so, the proper sequences are being generated and utilized within Hibernate/JPA and PostgreSQL.  Before, even if I declared the GenerationType as Sequence, none was being created.  Thanks for all of your help and advice in this matter!

Comment: Sometimes is needed to escape the names and put quotes like: name = "\"profile_seq\""

Answer (score 18):

GenerationType.IDENTITY

Comment: Much better than the accepted. While that one likely works, this requires no custom generator definitions.  Thanks!